# BashOperator doen't run bash file apache airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I just started using apache airflow. I am trying to run test.sh file from airflow, however it is not work.

Following is my code, file name is test.py

```
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('test', default_args=default_args)

# t1 and t2 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

create_command = "sh home/ubuntu/test/inst/scripts/test.sh"

if os.path.exists(create_command):
   t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id= 'cllTest',
        bash_command=create_command,
        dag=dag
   )
else:
    raise Exception("Cannot locate {}".format(create_command))

t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

when I run  python ~/airflow/dags/test.py, it doesn't throw any error.

However, When I run airflow list_dag, it throws following error:

```
[2017-02-15 20:20:02,741] {__init__.py:36} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2017-02-15 20:20:03,070] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags
[2017-02-15 20:20:03,135] {models.py:2040} ERROR - sh home/ubuntu/test/inst/scripts/test.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 2038, in resolve_template_files
    setattr(self, attr, env.loader.get_source(env, content)[0])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 187, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: sh home/ubuntu/test/inst/scripts/test.sh
```

I have tried to used [How to run bash script file in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146934/how-to-run-bash-script-file-in-airflow) for answer, it doesn't work

Where I am making mistake ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a space after .sh it should work
this is mentioned in the [confluence page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62694614) of airflow

```
t2 = BashOperator(
task_id='sleep',
bash_command="/home/batcher/test.sh", // This fails with `Jinja template not found` error
#bash_command="/home/batcher/test.sh ", // This works (has a space after)
dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 2):

use just the script path, without "sh": 
create_command = "/home/ubuntu/test/inst/scripts/test.sh"

also make sure that "airflow" user has permissions to execute "test.sh" script.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the "sh"  just set the command to "home/ubuntu/test/inst/scripts/test.sh"