# Run python script inside docker inside Airflow

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I have this code for airflow to execute python script inside docker :

```
a02_retrieve_2 = SSHExecuteOperator(
    task_id='a02_retrieve_2',
    ssh_hook=sshHook,
    dag=dag,
    bash_command= 'docker exec myDocker -i bash -c "  /opt/conda/bin/python aretrieve_2.py   --myarg  45  --myarg 35   "  '
)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.

But, the version with no argument works.

```
a02_retrieve_2 = SSHExecuteOperator(
    task_id='a02_retrieve_2',
    ssh_hook=sshHook,
    dag=dag,
    bash_command= 'docker exec myDocker -i bash -c "  /opt/conda/bin/python aretrieve_2.py  "  '
)
```

Error is :

```
Python script starts to run but Airflow is unable to catch up the python script parameters...
```

How to make the version with python script arguments works ?

Is this related to jinja template ?
[BashOperator doen't run bash file apache airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259298/bashoperator-doent-run-bash-file-apache-airflow)

Comment: How *does not work* look like? Any logs?

Comment: You already [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857940/execute-python-script-inside-docker-with-airflow) and probably didn't get an answer because you haven't provided enough information. What does it say in your logs.

Comment: airflow does not read the python arguments

Comment: Does everything work fine if you execute `bash -c "  /opt/conda/bin/python aretrieve_2.py   --myarg  45  --myarg 35   "` directly on the machine?

Comment: yes, of course.
this is related to jinja template in airflow

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by looking at the source code of bashoperator:
This uses popen

```
            self.log.info("Running command: %s", bash_command)
            sp = Popen(
                ['bash', fname],
                stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
                cwd=tmp_dir, env=self.env,
                preexec_fn=pre_exec)
```

https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/bash_operator.html