# Bash Operator error: No such file or directory in airflow

Tags: python, bash, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am a newbie to Airflow and struggling with BashOperator. I want to access a shell script using bash operatory in my dag.py.

I checked:
[How to run bash script file in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146934/how-to-run-bash-script-file-in-airflow)
and
[BashOperator doen't run bash file apache airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259298/bashoperator-doent-run-bash-file-apache-airflow/42571965)

on how to access shell script through bash operator.

This is what I did:

```
 cmd = "./myfirstdag/dag/lib/script.sh "

        t_1 = BashOperator(
            task_id='start',
            bash_command=cmd
        )
```

On running my recipe and checking in airflow I got the below error:

```
[2018-11-01 10:44:05,078] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - /tmp/airflowtmp7VmPci/startUDmFWW: line 1: ./myfirstdag/dag/lib/script.sh: No such file or directory
[2018-11-01 10:44:05,082] {bash_operator.py:80} INFO - Command exited with return code 127
[2018-11-01 10:44:05,083] {models.py:1361} ERROR - Bash command failed
```

Not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks !

EDIT NOTE: I assume that it's searching in some airflow tmp location rather than the path I provided. But how do I make it search for the right path.

Comment: Is `./myfirstdag/dag/lib/script.sh` relative to the `$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` directory?

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov no it's not. /myfirstdag/dag/lib/ is a different path while $AIRFLOW_HOME gives a different path when I tried.

Comment: what is then the *absolute* path to `script.sh`?

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov this /home/notebook/work/myfirstdag/dag/lib/ . I tried giving this too. It throws the same error.

Comment: Apparently, it's searching in a tmp directory that it's creating. That's what I understood from the source code. https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/27309b13f17402eaa61d4e4fede8785effa8bbb7/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py#L90 . Not sure how to make it search in the path I gave.

Comment: @Marvin you ever get a clear answer on this? None of the 4 answers below are accepted, or have many upvotes

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
bash_operator = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'task',
    bash_command = '${AIRFLOW_HOME}/myfirstdag/dag/lib/script.sh '
    dag = your_dag)
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks for answering this question! Could you please provide some details how this code solves the problem? :)

Comment: This solved my problem! If I'd change the bash_command to incorporate the extra space in the end to accomodate the jinja error, I'd always get a script not found error. Using the env variable solved it for good, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For those running a docker version.

I had this same issue, took me a while to realise the problem, the behaviour can be different with docker. When the DAG is run it moves it tmp file, if you do not have airflow on docker this is on the same machine. with my the docker version it moves it to another container to run, which of course when it is run would not have the script file on.

check the task logs carefully, you show see this happen before the task is run.
This may also depend on your airflow-docker setup.

Comment: i am using docker version only. How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. It needs to have a full file path to your bash file.

```
cmd = "/home/notebook/work/myfirstdag/dag/lib/script.sh "

t_1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='start',
    bash_command=cmd
)
```

Comment: have tried. Doesn't work. Please refer to the comments above.

Comment: Can you for the sake of debugging, try removing the `.sh` extension and the run with `cmd=bash /home/notebook/work/myfirstdag/dag/lib/script` and let me know it it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of the path you defined?

```
cmd = "./myfirstdag/dag/lib/script.sh "
```

With the heading **.** it means it is relative to the path where you execute your command.

Could you try this?

```
cmd = "find . -type f"
```

Comment: I tried without the . too. It gives the same error.

Comment: Try setting cmd="pwd" and gives us output of a find - ls in the corresponding directory?

Comment: I tried that already. It gives a tmp directory which gets deleted after every run. But I am not sure how do I set the path to the one where my script is present.

Comment: Ok, so put the find -ls as the cmd itself, and we will see where is located the myfirstdag/dag/lib/script.sh

Comment: Seems like it cannot locate that using the find command. It's because it cannot find the directory itself. So I did `cd /home ; ls -lrt`. All I got is just one folder as `airflow/` where as I have two other folders in it named `example/` and `notebook/` which isn't showing when I am doing it through the bashOperator. All I get is this: `Running command: cd / ; cd home/; ls 
Output:
airflow`

Comment: You misunderstood me, I've updated my answer consequently for the command you should try.

Comment: This is what I got : `Running command: find -ls
Output:
22273487      4 drwx------   2 root     root         4096 Nov  5 08:46 .
22273488      4 -rw-------   1 root     root            8 Nov  5 08:46 ./startRIKEG9`

Comment: Ok, so it's 100% sure, there is no myfirstdag/dag/lib/script.sh in a subdirectory of this temporary directory. So you can't either use the relative path **./myfirstdag/dag/lib/script.sh** , or you priorly need to perform action to copy missing files.

Comment: yep. That's what I am looking for. Either how to copy the file to this location or access the path I gave.

Comment: Where is located your script.sh file on your computer?
In addition, maybe you should add **dag=dag** definition in your bash operator, See https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#it-s-a-dag-definition-file

Answer (score 0):

try running this:

```
path = "/home/notebook/work/myfirstdag/dag/lib/script.sh"
copy_script_cmd = 'cp ' + path + ' .;'
execute_cmd = './script.sh'

t_1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='start',
    bash_command=copy_script_cmd + execute_cmd
)
```