# Airflow BashOperator Fails to Find Script in Mounted Volume

Tags: python, bash, docker-compose, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm facing an issue while using the BashOperator in an Airflow to run a Python script. It is running inside docker container. The problem is that it can't find the path to the script, even though I've mounted a volume where the script is located.

So I tried executing `pwd` command inside bash operator, it shows:

```
with DAG(
    "Some Dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    description="",
    schedule=timedelta(days=1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["useful tag"],
) as dag:
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="script_to_execute",
        bash_command=f'echo $HOME && source opt/home/.pyenv/versions/my-env/bin/activate && python opt/home/path_to_script/runner.py
    )
```

just placed under volumes home dir:

```
volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}:/opt/home
```

this is inside docker container

```
default@235545bc0984:/opt$ ls
airflow  home  microsoft
default@235545bc0984:/opt$ pwd
/opt
default@235545bc0984:/opt$ cd home/
default@235545bc0984:/opt/home$ pwd
/opt/home
```

```
'echo $HOME && pwd && ls -la $HOME/***
 Output:
[2023-11-02, 19:59:41 PKT] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - /home/***
[2023-11-02, 19:59:41 PKT] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - /tmp/***tmpgmauypmw
[2023-11-02, 19:59:41 PKT] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - ls: cannot access '/home/***/***': No such file or directory
```

I'm using an official docker-compose file from airflow:
[docker-compose](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#fetching-docker-compose-yaml)

I've searched various Stack Overflow posts, but I couldn't find a solution that addresses my problem. The closest answer I found was this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56263688/11974413), but the author didn't share a solution. If you have a solution to my problem, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: We need to see how you are mounting the volume. My guess is not correctly because your path inside the container really shouldn't be /home/ec2-user/... This tells me that you are entering the host path, not the path to which the volume is mounted in the container.

Comment: Can you `docker exec` into the container to check the existence of directories/files ?

Comment: @LeonardoGazdek Edited my post and added more info. Thanks

Comment: @Philippe added, could you check my post again? thanks

Comment: Regarding `ls: cannot access '/home/***/***': No such file or directory`, you need to check `/home/***/***` exists when you `docker exec` into the container..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your setup right, but in the operator you gave you use `opt/home/...` which is almost certainly wrong. I think you want `/opt/home/...`. Without the leading slash, it's a relative path, and will be resolved starting from the working directory. If that's `/opt` (as in the `ls` and `pwd` listings you gave, `opt/home/...` is equivalent to `/opt/opt/home/...` which doesn't exist.