# Airflow : Bash command failed

Tags: python, bash, jar, sh, airflow

Im trying  to run a `.jar` DAG via Airlfow 
i have a `.sh` file which call all the libraires needed for the execution of the jar in question, but i still face the same error with the `BashOperator`, here is the content of `.py` file :

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime


import os
import sys

create_command  = "/home/user/Images/Job senority new colecttion /Skill/Skill_run.sh "

default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 5, 03),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_success': False,
    'provide_context': True
}
dag = DAG(dag_id='Skill_batch', default_args=default_args)


t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id= 'Batch_file_sh',
        bash_command='create_command',
        dag=dag
   )

t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='task_1',
        bash_command='echo Hello, This is my first DAG in Airflow!',
        dag=dag
    )

t3 = BashOperator(
       task_id = 'runjar',
       dag = dag,
       bash_command = 'java -cp /home/user/Images/Job senority new colecttion /Skill/skill.jar '

t2 >> t1 >> t3
 `
```

here is the log from airflow ui :

```
[2019-05-08 15:33:24,523] {bash_operator.py:104} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpIghU_M/Batch_file_shPuscAS
[2019-05-08 15:33:24,523] {bash_operator.py:114} INFO - Running command: create_command
[2019-05-08 15:33:24,527] {bash_operator.py:123} INFO - Output:
[2019-05-08 15:33:24,528] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - /tmp/airflowtmpIghU_M/Batch_file_shPuscAS: ligne 1: create_command : commande introuvable
[2019-05-08 15:33:24,528] {bash_operator.py:131} INFO - Command exited with return code 127
[2019-05-08 15:33:24,532] {__init__.py:1580} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 135, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
AirflowException: Bash command failed
```

I checked that the DAG is under `AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` repository and allowed the `.sh` and `.jar` file to be executable with `chmod +x file.sh` 
I also tried some of the answers  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146934/how-to-run-bash-script-file-in-airflow), but the same situation airflow doses not recognize the .jar path directory.

Comment: `cmd` is windows-specific. You seem to be on linux right?

Comment: Right sorry, just made a mistake when copying the code, and yes i am on Ubuntu 16.04 and `Airflow version` v1.10.3

Comment: Please correct your code if there's still an issue, because it's not clear if this is resolved or not?

Comment: @bosnjak it's not revolved yet, i did check the error in the code

Comment: But now the error part doesn't correlate with the code. The error is still about the missing `cmd` command which you removed.

Comment: @bosnjak i did repost the log here, but it's the same error ,

Comment: The error is not from Airflow, the execution of your `Skill_run.sh` script failed: `Command exited with return code 127`. Airflow will take a return code from the script and if it's non-zero it will fail the operator. Check inside the script why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the same issue.

Need to install the java package.

First, update the apt package index with:

```
sudo apt update
```

Once the package index is updated install the default Java OpenJDK package with:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Verify the installation, by running the following command which will print the Java version:

```
java -version
```

The output will look something like this:

```
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```